How does the Promise on requestFullscreen() actually work?
I'm implementing a application in a web browser that has a button to toggle full screen using the Fullscreen Browser API.
I had assumed that I could .then() the promise returned by requestFullscreen() to determine the new screen space using window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth, but it returns the original non-full screen values instead.
However, switching to full screen does trigger the resize event which does correctly give the innerWidth and height.
It appears as if this Promise resolves before the element is actually made full screen.
For example:
document.getElementById('fullScreenButton').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        document.getElementById('container').requestFullscreen()
        .then( () => {
            console.log( `element: ${document.fullscreenElement}` );
            console.log( `height in then: ${window.innerHeight}` );
        });
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    console.log( `height in resize event: ${window.innerHeight}`);
});

The output from this is:
element: [object HTMLDivElement]
height in then: 673
height in resize event: 1080

The then() picked up the original window height and then immediately after the resize event picked up the full screen height.
I realise I could just grab the screen dimensions with screen.width and screen.height instead of innerHeight/innerWidth and obviously I have a work around since the resize event triggers and does what I need, but I would like to understand how this Promise actually works compared to how I expected it to work.
Thank you to anyone who can offer me some clarity :)

I think you are requesting full screen for document.getElementById('container'). so only this element will be resized

Yeah, that's what is intended. In terms of checking if it makes a difference, requestFullscreen() has to be on an HTML element and the document body element also returns the same results.
